# GDAX Sandbox Fix connectivity

Tags: java

Not getting any response from GDAX Sandbox HTTP connection. Trying to connect gdax sandbox for fix connectivity to place an order.

Connected URL = https://fix-public.sandbox.gdax.com

```
java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:851)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:848)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:678)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1569)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1474)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at com.coinbase.exchange.api.HttpConnection.main(HttpConnection.java:43)
```

Sample Code to make HTTP connection and upgrade to FIX:

```
try {
    String httpsURL = "https://fix-public.sandbox.gdax.com";
    URL url = new URL(httpsURL);
    //URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Upgrade" );
    conn.setRequestProperty("Upgrade", "fix" );

    conn.connect();

    System.out.println(" Connected url = " + url.toString());
    System.out.println(" getResponseCode = " + conn.getResponseCode());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox was shut down early to mid-2017. I have documented this in the [gdax-java](https://github.com/irufus/gdax-java) library. No comms was sent out to devs about it as far as I can tell but it was mentioned in their community pages IIRC.